# Excel VBA: search a string to find the first non-text character

Tags: regex, excel, vba

Cells contain a mixture of characters within a string, such as:

> Abcdef_8765
>     QWERTY3_JJHH
>     Xyz9mnop

I need to find the first non `A-Za-z` character so that I can strip out the subsequent remainder of the string.

So the results would be:

> Abcdef
>    QWERTY
>    Xyz

I know how to do this if I know exactly what character I'm looking for, but I'm not intuitively grasping how to find ANY character *other than* `A-Za-z`.

Btw, this is intended to be used within a [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) solution.

====================

**EDIT:**

**I've had success with the following...**

```
a = "abc123"
b = Len(a)

For x = 1 To b

c = (Mid(a, x, 1) Like "[a-zA-Z]")
If c = False Then
d = Left(a, x - 1)
Exit Sub
End If

Next x
```

**Have I stumbled upon a suitable solution, or is this destined to break? 
I ask only because I look at Doug Glancy's solution and it seems much more substantial. 
(btw, I have not yet tested Doug's solution)**

Comment: As Doug suggests, Regex is the way to go.  If the example pattern doesn't fit you can easily adapt it.

Comment: You can do as above, but for repetitive use the character by character search is slower, and the [tag:regexp] will be more readily able to handle more complex parsing rules.

Comment: @brettdj : 2 points of thanks. First of all thanks for the edit to my post. I will be sure to incorporate blockquotes in a similar fashion on future posts. Secondly thanks for your regex solution. It handles the precise type of data that I referred to in my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp) below looks to remove from the first non `A-Z` character.

```
Function StrChange(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegEx As Object

Set objRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegEx
    .ignorecase = True
    .Pattern = "^([a-z]+)([^a-z].*)"
    .Global = True
     StrChange = .Replace(strIn, "$1")
End With
End Function
```

Comment: +1 Nice one Dave. But it will fail on `5_ABCD`. I know that OP didn't specify that the cell can start with a number as well though.

Comment: Added this pattern for the invalid string - `"^([a-z]+)([^a-z].*)"` so any no matches are untouched. The prior version didn't actually fail as such, as `5_ABCD` was still returned as `5_ABCD`. But other invalid strings such as `5_ABCD_FRED_0` would have been partially changed (although no error message).

Comment: Dave but my understanding is that it shouldn't return anything for say `5_Siddharth_Rout`

Comment: Sid, I was working on the premise the strings would be manipulated if they matched, otherwise left alone. So by default I left it intact. If it is required to be nulled, then I will add a `Test` to the `Regexp`

Comment: For the type of data that I am working with, this solution fits the need EXACTLY. Many thanks! I have used regex on the worksheet level  in google docs, but I have never done so inside VBA - mostly due to the complexity of the solutions that I've come across in the past. But this solution is straight to the point, and I am not uncomfortable using it because I feel that I can understand it readily enough. Those of you who (obviously!) know this stuff well may not struggle to follow some of these solutions, but for the regex novice, the "straight to the point" solution is always the best :)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple way which doesn't use RegEx. I am deliberately not using RegEx as the other two answer are based on RegEx. `RegEx` is definitely faster but this is almost equally fast. The difference in speed is almost negligible.

```
Function GetWord(Rng As Range)
    Dim i As Long, pos As Long

    For i = 1 To Len(Rng.Value)
        Select Case Asc(Mid(Rng.Value, i, 1))
            Case 65 To 90, 97 To 122
            Case Else: pos = i: Exit For
        End Select
    Next i

    GetWord = Left(Rng.Value, pos - 1)
End Function
```

**Usage**:

```
=GetWord(A1)
```

[image]

**EDIT**:

Followup from comments. Fine tuned the code (Courtesy @brettdj) .

```
Function GetWord(Rng As Range)
    Dim i As Long, pos As Long
    Dim sString As String

    sString = UCase$(Rng.Value)

    For i = 1 To Len(sString)
        Select Case Asc(Mid$(sString, i, 1))
        Case 65 To 90
        Case Else: pos = i: Exit For
        End Select
    Next i

    GetWord = Left(Rng.Value, pos - 1)
End Function
```

**More Followup.**

Here is something which I had never tried before. I did an actual test of my code vs RegXp and I was surprised to see my code was faster than `RegXp` which I had not anticipated.

I tested it on 10k cells and each cell had a string of 2256 of length

The string that I put in Cell `A1:A10000` is

`aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeSiddharth5RoutaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeSiddharth5RoutaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeSiddharth5RoutaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeSiddharth5RoutaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeSiddharth5RoutaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeSiddharth5RoutaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeSiddharth5RoutaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeSiddharth5Rout`

[image]

Next I ran this test

[image]

Comment: "The difference in speed is almost negligible" - depends on how long your strings are and how many you have :) Using Mid$ and perhaps Ucase$ so it searches 1 not 2 ASC ranges would tweak it a little further

Comment: @brettdj: I did a small test and my code was faster than RegExp. Updating the above post in few minutes

Comment: Very interesting. Although there is a relatively early exit from your 2256 length string (at position 291) for the loop. The other issue would be the o/h in calling the RegExp object 10000 times, calling it once in a variant array would help I think

Comment: @brettdj: Yup. even if you push that towards the end, i.e the non text character is at `2054`th position then `RegXp` is just 1 second faster in the above test scanario. So we are back to `"The difference in speed is almost negligible"` :D

Comment: @brettdj: Um, the idea of trying both on an array looks pretty tempting :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Agree,and that's what I meant :) I'd be curious to see on a like for like basis if removing the regexp overhead with the variant moves it beyond negligible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple regular expression to specify a numeral followed by anything and use this function to replace anything that matches that pattern:

```
Function Regex_Replace(strOriginal As String, strPattern As String, strReplacement, varIgnoreCase As Boolean) As String
Dim objRegExp As Object

Set objRegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegExp
    .Pattern = strPattern
    .IgnoreCase = varIgnoreCase
    .Global = True
End With

Regex_Replace = objRegExp.Replace(strOriginal, strReplacement)
Set objRegExp = Nothing
End Function
```

You'd call it like this:

```
Sub DeleteAfterNums()
Dim cell As Excel.Range

'Change "Selection" to your range
For Each cell In Selection
'"\d.+" is a numeral and whatever follows it
cell.Value = Regex_Replace(cell.Value, "\d.+", "", True)
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Doug. I haven't tested this yet, but this handles only numbers but not characters such as underscores or dashes or backslashes, etc right? Because I need to isolate the left-most a-zA-Z only. Any other character (not just numbers) must be found and parsed. Btw, I have edited my original post with code that has so far tested well for that need.

Comment: + 1 Nicely done :) You code works when the cell starts with a number as well for example `5_ABCD`. However, your code will fail on `sidffgS_5gfsfdgsfdg`

Comment: 5th4x4, as is clear by now, your understanding of the limitations of my answer is correct. Looks like you've got two other good ones, plus what you discovered on your own, to round it out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a lightweight and fast method that avoids regex/reference additions, thus helping with overhead and transportability should that be an advantage.

```
Public Function GetText(xValue As String) As Variant

For GetText = 1 To Len(xValue)
    If UCase(Mid(xValue, GetText, 1)) Like "[!A-Z]" Then GetText = Left(xValue, GetText - 1): Exit Function
Next

GetText = xValue

End Function
```

This is then called by using GetText("Submission String") from vba or prepended with a "=" from within a cell formula.