# Finding the last letter in the cell

Tags: vba, excel, split, string-concatenation

I have multiple rows of strings that are both text and numbers. I want to do a text to columns that separates this by spaces except for the first and last parts.

If I run the text to columns delimited by spaces then it splits up strings that I don't want split up.

Example:

```
Quarterly Performance Numbers 999,999.99 12.00 1.00 2.00 3.00 4.00 Dec 09, 2013
```

Becomes:

```
Quarterly|Performance|Numbers|999,999.99|12.00|1.00|2.00|3.00|4.00|Dec|09,|2013
```

What I want:

```
Quarterly Performance Numbers|999,999.99|12.00|1.00|2.00|3.00|4.00|Dec 09, 2013
```

The problem is the part is varying lengths and number of words (anywhere from 3 to 6).

Is there a way I can create text qualifiers around those two strings in VBA?

```
Sub Macro3()


Dim i As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 1 To LastRow

Cells(i, 2).Value = Mid(Cells(i, 1), 29, 37)
Cells(i, 3).Value = Right(Cells(i, 1), 12)
Cells(i, 1).Value = Left(Cells(i, 1), 37)

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Where's this data coming from? Can you convince the source to export it as CSV instead?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do this in VBA, and if you show us your attempt, we can help you debug it.

Comment: Charles:I tried. The source only puts things in PDFs but said they may switch in the future. For the time being I just copied it into excel.

Comment: Jean: I like your style. Give me a minute.

Comment: How much does the format vary? Is it pretty much always this set of data, just varying numbers?

Comment: The first string ranges from 3 words to 6 words. The number of numbers is always 6. The date at the end is always in MMM DD, YYYY format.

Comment: Jean: I added what I had come up with so far. Unfortunately it only works for the handful of cells that have a specific length.

Comment: Hmm. Is there a value that you know will never be present in the data? Can there be negative numbers?

Comment: There can be negative numbers. Extremely large numbers like 100 Million+ are unlikely but not impossible.

Comment: I found an answer to another question that is similar and possibly helpful. It uses something called RegEx.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20296443/excel-vba-search-a-string-to-find-the-first-non-text-character

Comment: A regular expression (aka, regex) is definitely a potential solution! Just be aware that there's an old joke among programmers: I had a problem and I decided to use regular expressions. Now I have two problems. (http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way that works. As I was warned, RegEx ended up being more of a problem than a solution. My method isn't pretty but it gets the job done. I count the number of spaces by subtracting the length of the string by the length of the string after I remove the spaces. The only variable in spaces comes from the number of spaces in the description and so if i subtract the 8 minimum spaces from the total spaces i can use it to replace the Nth space with ";". I do this 7 times and all of my columns come out correctly in delimited text to columns. Thanks everyone. Sorry if my explanation sucks.

```
Sub Macro14()

Dim i As Long
Dim smaller As String
Dim spaces As Integer
Dim fixed As String
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 1 To LastRow

smaller = Replace(Cells(i, 1), " ", "")
spaces = Len(Cells(i, 1)) - Len(smaller) - 8

fixed = Cells(i, 1).Value
fixed = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(fixed, " ", ";", spaces) 'after desc
fixed = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(fixed, " ", ";", spaces) 'after value
fixed = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(fixed, " ", ";", spaces) 'after %age
fixed = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(fixed, " ", ";", spaces) 'after first perf column
fixed = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(fixed, " ", ";", spaces) 'after second perf column
fixed = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(fixed, " ", ";", spaces) 'after third perf column
fixed = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(fixed, " ", ";", spaces) 'after fourth perf column/before the date

Cells(i, 1).Value = fixed

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Test()
    Dim sContent, oMatch, arrParsed(), sResult
    sContent = "Quarterly Performance Numbers 999,999.99 12.00 1.00 2.00 3.00 4.00 Dec 09, 2013"
    arrParsed = Array()
    With New RegExp ' Tools - References - add "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" or use With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "(?:(?:[a-z ]+(?= )){3,6}|(?:-*[\d,.]+(?= ))|(?:[a-z]{3} \d{2}, \d{4}))"
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        For Each oMatch In .Execute(sContent)
            ReDim Preserve arrParsed(UBound(arrParsed) + 1)
            arrParsed(UBound(arrParsed)) = oMatch.Value
        Next
    End With
    ' here you can use arrParsed
    sResult = Join(arrParsed, ";")
    MsgBox sResult
End Sub
```

Comment: This works for most rows. Can you help me understand the pattern? Also it seems to delete things.

Comment: My clue is to start from eg [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1400241x.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1400241x.aspx), also it's convenient to use a special Notepad++ RegEx Helper plugin or another one tool for pattern creation. For what strings that pattern doesn't work? I guess I've forgot minus for negative numbers?

Comment: There are some first strings that are hyphenated where it just deletes part of the string. I'm checking out that link. Thanks.